# Tab Order in interface builder?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, tab-ordering

Perhaps the hour is late, but I can't find where I can set the overall Tab Order of my interface viewer dialog, just like I can with Visual Studio.

am I missing something? The tab order is all crooked. Command-R to simulate shows it.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a screenshot of the “tab order” you're referring to, and what you find “crooked”.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The Cocoa term you're looking for is "key view loop".  Use the `initialFirstResponder` and `nextKeyView` outlets to connect the views together in the order you'd like to tab through them.

This is mentioned in the documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Tasks/KeyboardInterfaceWindows.html).

Note that the items which can receive keyboard focus will change depending on the Full Keyboard Access setting (in System Preferences > Keyboard); if disabled, tabbing will skip over various items in your key view loop.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to set the order from the Interface builder itself? I mean, if you just build something from scratch it will have a given tab order, based i believe on the order of the control creation. If i add the last control in the "first position" on the view itself, it will still be last although it looks as if it should have been first. I guess my question is whether there's a way to tweak that ordering from interface builder itself, not programmatically if possible.

Comment: Yes, when I say "outlets...connect the views together" I'm talking about stuff you can do from Interface Builder.  You use the window's initialFirstResponder's outlet to set the "first position".

Comment: For posterity, a gist that highlights the current first responder and prints the key-view loop in the console: https://gist.github.com/mittsh/6668638

Comment: Hi will it be depend on OSX version.. because tab order working by default in 10.9.2 OSX but not working in 10.8.5 OSX.. any help please.

Comment: Also, make sure "Refuses First Responder" is not disabled in IB.

Answer (score 2):

Let the outlets are named as a, b and c. Mac default tab order is `a -> b -> c -> a`

But Your desired tab order is `a -> c -> b ->a` :

[image]

Using IB:

Set `a` as the `initialFirstResponder`.

Then put the nextKeyView accordingly as `a to c, c to b and c to a`.

But I prefer using codes, here it become easier to add more. As in complex UI there may be 30+ controls and you might require to shuffle and even insert new control!!!

So you can achieve the same as :

```
[self.a setNextKeyView:self.c];
[self.c setNextKeyView:self.b];
[self.b setNextKeyView:self.a];
```

Comment: This does not work when some of the views are hidden by default, and become visible later.

Comment: @Etan: for such cases you need to take care by setting its nextKeyView runtime based on what view is visible(on top).

Answer (score 0):

I have found that placing the group of textfields in a separate view will help control the order in which the elements get their focus.

I tested in the simulator and on an iPad. It worked well for me.