# Defining the order that [tab] key presses follow in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, layout, swift2

I have the following application layout:

```
|    Text Field A    | |  Button A  |
|    Text Field B    | |  Button B  |
```

In most applications, <kbd>tab</kbd> functionality which allows for jumping from one element to another element works in a logical order (i.e. `Text Field A - Button A - Text Field B - Button B` etc).

It seems quite the contrary when I try and implement something similar in Interface Builder: instead of going in a logical sequence as defined above, it goes in the sequence `Text Field A - Text Field B - Button A - Button B`, which does not feel logical or natural.

I have looked at `nextResponder()`, but nothing avails from it.

**Question(s):**

- How is the sequence determined automatically?
- Is it possible to modify this automatically determined sequence?

Comment: I think this was already answered here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261865/tab-order-in-interface-builder

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't know it was called a 'key view loop'. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found that placing the group of elements in a separate view will help control the order in which the elements get their focus.

I have tried this in the simulator and on an iPad and it worked well for me.