# tab key to change fields in order mentioned: Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Im new to swift.In one of my application i have 5 text fields in story board.

Text Field 1
Text Field 2
Text Field 3
Text Field 4
Text Field 5

When I run app in simulator, on pressing tab, I need the text field cursor to move in order mentioned i.e, starting with `text field 1 -> text field 3 -> text field 5 -> text field 4 -> text field 2`

I tried checking below code but was not successful

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {     
    TextField1.becomeFirstResponder()
    TextField3.nextResponder()
    TextField5.nextResponder()
    TextField4.nextResponder()
    TextField2.nextResponder()  
}
```

Kindly let me know how i can achieve this in swift

Your response will really be helpful

Comment: But will users be able to press the tab key on their phones?

Comment: I think this was already answered... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261865/tab-order-in-interface-builder

Comment: When the user presses "Done"  once value entered into textField1, Im expecting the cursor to directly go onto textField 3 instead of textField2

Comment: hi Chris, I ve checked the link but couldnt find nextKeyView in code. So just wondering how i can achieve same